# Crop rasterLayer with SpatialPolygonDataFrame leaves out part of the target region R

Tags: r, maps, raster, map-projections

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
library(rgdal)
```

I am trying to crop a raster layer based on polygon: sample data (~45MB) can be found here [sample data for illustration](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ykh7mqtqqh0j51s/data.zip?dl=0):

```
dat<- raster('data.nc')# make a subset 
dat
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 824, 935, 770440  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 10000, 10000  (x, y)
extent      : -5000, 9345000, -5000, 8235000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
data source : C:\Users\data.nc 
names       : Total.Precipitation 
zvar        : Total.Precipitation
```

As `coord. ref is = NA`, I assign a polar stereographic projection based on information from the [website](https://weather.gc.ca/grib/grib2_RDPA_ps10km_e.html) of the data provider.

```
projj=CRS("+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=90 +lon_0=-100 +k=0.994 +x_0=2000000 +y_0=2000000 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
proj4string(dat) <- projj
    #rx <- projectRaster(from=dat, crs=wgs84.p4s)
```

Then transform the bbox shapefile to `projj`

```
    shgrid <- spTransform(Prairie.Boundaries, projj)# transform to dat spat reference
    plot(dat)
    plot(shgrid,add=T)# this gives
```

[image]

## CROPPING

```
    cr <- crop(dat, extent(shgrid)) 
    plot(cr)
    fr <- rasterize(shgrid, cr) 
    dat1<- mask(x=cr, mask=fr)
    levelplot(dat1)
```

## OUTPUT:

The cropped image shows only part of canada but I want all of Canada.

What did I miss within my code? Could it be the projection?

Besides I would prefer the axes labels in latlon coordinates.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: If you do `plot(dat)` and `plot(shgrid, add=TRUE)` you see why this happens.

Comment: @RobertH you are right. I have edited my question. How can I get `shgrid` to align with `dat`? Thanks.

Comment: It is hard to say. It might be that your data only cover this part of Canada. If not, that suggests that you need correct your coordinate reference system. On the website you refer to I only see "polar-stereographic"; that is insufficient info. There is one here: http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/8237/   with "central_meridian =249" (which suggests that a longitude from 0 to 360 is used, starting in Greenwich). So this would be -111 degrees in normal geographic speak. So many places where this can go wrong.

Comment: I used `+proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=77 +lat_0=63.390675 +lon_0=-91.86666666666666 +x_0=6200000 +y_0=3000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs` and got the new image above. I think it has to do with the projection. `shgrid` is still displaced from where it should be.